# Does false discovery rate estimate some population quantity?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

False discovery rate (FDR) is defined as

> FDR = FP / (TP + FP).

Does it estimate some population quantity, independent of sample, when the sample satisfies some condition?

To make it clearer, True positive rate is defined as

> TPR = TP/ (TP + FN)

If all the points in the sample come from a sample distribution $F$ in the alternative hypothesis, true positive rate estimates $P_{X \sim F}($ reject null $)$.

Comment: How is the TPR related to the question?

Comment: @JohnRos: If all the true positives in a sample comes from an alternative distribution $F$, TPR can be seen as an estimate of $P_{X\sim F}(\text{ reject null })$. But for FDR, because its denominator is the reported positives which is not population dependent, I don't think it can be estimate of any population quantity.

Comment: I see. I still feel the presence of FTP might be more confusing than clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

The FDR of an inference procedure cannot estimate any quantity, as it is, by itself, a fixed quantity. Think of it as a generalization of the type I error-- which you would never call "an estimate".

One can however, estimate the FDR of a given inference procedure. Try [1] as a starting reference.

[1] Storey, John D. "A direct approach to false discovery rates." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 64.3 (2002): 479-498.

Answer (score 0):

Efron and Tibshirani's new book [Computer Age Statistical Inference](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf) offers an intuitive understanding to what is being estimated. Let me summarize their message graphically.

The (Bayesian) underlying idea is that observations come from a mixture of two distributions:

- $\pi_0 \: N$ observations from the null density $f_0(z)$
- $(1-\pi_0) \: N$ observations from alternative density $f_1(z)$.

What is observed is the mixture of those two:

- $f(z) = \pi_0 \cdot f_0(z) + (1-\pi_0) \cdot f_1(z)$

[image]

The (Bayesian) definitions are:

- $\text{Fdr} = \frac{\pi_0 \: (1-F_0(z_0))}{(1-F(z))}$  (a fraction of the tail areas)
- $\text{fdr} = \frac{\pi_0 \: f_0(z_0)}{f(z)}$  (a fraction of the tail densities)

As shown below, Fdr is equivalent to the Benjamini hocherg FDR when $\pi_0 \approx 1$ (which is the case in most bioinformatics studies)

[image]